# 1.9.2.2 - New products created not displaying in front end categories or search

Tags: products, ce-1.9.2.2

I'm working on upgrades to 1.9.2.2 on a test site before rolling out to production. When testing adding products, any new product I create post-upgrade does not display in the catalog or search, while any products that already existed prior to the upgrade display in both the catalog and search with no problems.

I've validated that the products are created correctly (all are being created manually in the admin interface), they show enabled, visibility is catalog/search.  While I normally don't use manage stock, I've tried both enabling and disabling manage stock on the products and confirmed they show In Stock with sufficient quantity.

Any suggestions?

Comment: You should reindex your database

Comment: That was one of the first things I tried - no luck.